# How to open a searched file in Finder?

Tags: finder, spotlight, search, alfred

When I search a file in Spotlight, it provides me a good result. But the problem is that I want to open the file in Finder, instead of directly opening the file in an application. How can I open in searched files in Finder, meaning that I want to open the folder that contains the searched files in Finder?

If I can do what I want in another application like Alfred, that will be also wonderful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highlight the result in Spotlight, then **press ⌘↩︎**. This will open the containing folder in Finder.

---

Alfred will also let you do this, with a bit more customisation:

[image]